# How to remove leading zero or make it optional for MaskedEditExtender

Tags: c#, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the AjaxControlToolKit MaskedEditExtender on a textbox to enforce the input as a time formatted in en-US culture using the AM/PM designator. It works fine except that it pre-pends a leading zero to times having a one digit hour (e.g. 09:00 AM instead of 9:00 AM). Below is the relevant code:

```
<ajt:MaskedEditExtender 
 ID="MaskedEditExtenderTextBoxAtValue" TargetControlID="TextBoxAtValue" 
 MaskType="Time" Mask="99:99" CultureName="en-US" 
 AutoComplete="false"ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true" 
 AcceptAMPM="true"  runat="server"  />
```